# DO loop increment problem in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I have a problem while using a do loop in fortran,

```
REAL W,V,X 
DO 50 W = 0.5,5.0,0.5
DO 50 V = 10.0,1000.0,10.0
DO 50 X = 1.0,10,1.0
C=(W*V*X)/1000.0
WRITE(*,*) W,V,X,C
50 CONTINUE
STOP
END
```

If I gave this it is showing that only integers needs to be used in do loop, is there any way to give integers in do loop or any other way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Use integers as your looping indices

```
      REAL W,V,X
      INTEGER I,J,K

      DO 50 I = 1,10
        DO 50 J = 1,100
          DO 50 K = 1,10

            W = 0.5 * I
            V = 10.0 * J
            X = 1.0 * K

            C=(W*V*X)/1000.0
            WRITE(*,*) W,V,X,C

50    CONTINUE
      STOP
      END
```

Comment: For safer programming practices, you probably should have `w= 0.5 * real(i)` (and likewise for `v` and `x`). Or, for simplicity: `c=real(i*j*k)/1000.0`

Comment: @KyleKanos No need for extra verbosity here, integer `I` will be upgraded to `REAL` as long as `W` is declared as `REAL`.

Comment: @IRO-bot: 5.*(3/4) /= (5.*3)/4 -- the first is zero while the latter is 3.75. Mixed-type math *should* be avoided, but it is not always necessary.

Comment: Better these days to avoid using the same labeled `CONTINUE` statement as the end of multiple loops; use matching `END DO` statements.

Comment: @KyleKanos Integer division is a different issue, and not present in the example above. :)

Comment: @IRO-bot: The issue is mixed-type math, not integer division. Mixed-type math *ought* to be avoided because there *can* be some problems. True it is not a problem here, but it should be avoided nonetheless.

Comment: @KyleKanos Fortran standard takes care of mixed-mode expressions. The weaker type variable is always coerced to a stronger type variable. There is nothing unsafe about mixed-mode expressions. I agree that it may be confusing if the programmer/reader is not familiar with the language. The example you provided to show your point has nothing to do with mixed-mode expressions, but with integer division, i.e. 5.*0 /= 15./4, we get it. Did not mean to start an argument, but I did find your comment to be unnecessary nit-picking at an otherwise good answer. Have a good day. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish the same thing by incrementing a real variable by adding your step value, and using an if then to exit the loop. Clunky, but should work.

The last time I programmed in Fortran, I used punch cards and an IBM-360, so I'm not going to pretend I remember the syntax.